# Powershell Remote Copy fails, locally it works

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

We have logfile on a server A in a different location (no UNC Path access) and we wish to copy the file to server B. This successfully works with `Copy-Item -FromSession` (run on Server B) as long as the file is closed. So we can successfully copy the previous day's logs but not today's.

```
$cred = Get-OurUserCredentials
$sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ServerA -Credential $cred -Authentication Negotiate
$LogFile = "D:\log\tomcat\access.20180227.log" 
Copy-Item -FromSession $sess $LogFile "D:\logs\tomcat\" -Force
```

However, we can locally copy the active log of today if we run `Copy-Item` locally on server A. It's only `Copy-Item -FromSession` on server B which fails with:

> Copy-Item : The process cannot access the file 'D:\log\tomcat\access.20180227.log' because it is being used by another process.
>       At line:11 char:2

As a workaround we could create a local task on server A to create a local copy but why is this necessary?

Why does Copy-Item behave differently when run remotely and can we "fix" it's behaviour so it copies the log remotely as it would locally.

Answer (score 1):

A version of the answer proposed in the OP but avoiding the need for a scheduled task.

```
    $cred = Get-OurUserCredentials
    $sess = New-PSSession -ComputerName $ServerA -Credential $cred -Authentication Negotiate

    #ScriptBlock to copy file locally
    $SB =
    {
        #Create variables on the remote machine avoid havin gto pass to scriptblock
        $LogFile = "D:\log\tomcat\access.20180227.log" 
        $TempDes = "temporarylocationhere"

        Copy-Item -Path $LogFile -Destination $Des
    }

    #optional scriptblock to clean up
    $SB2 =
    {
        Remove-Item -Path $TempDes -force
    }

    #Run the copy file scriptblock
    Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock $SB

    #Copy file
    Copy-Item -FromSession $sess $TempDes "D:\logs\tomcat\" -Force                           #"

    #Run clean up scriptblock
    Invoke-Command -Session $sess -ScriptBlock $SB2
```

Comment: A neat solution which certainly works - thanks! I'm gonna leave the question open for a while to see if it can be done with `Copy-Item` alone.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a [`PSDrive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive?view=powershell-6) to map the remote location and then copy the file to or from that drive?

> The New-PSDrive cmdlet creates temporary and persistent drives that
>   are mapped to or associated with a location in a data store, such as a
>   network drive, a directory on the local computer, or a registry key,
>   and persistent Windows mapped network drives that are associated with
>   a file system location on a remote computer.

Example using your code:

```
# Change the ServerNameToCopyTo below    
New-PSDrive -Name "Remote" -PSProvider "FileSystem" -Root "\\ServerNameToCopyTo\log\tomcat\" 
$LogFile = "D:\log\tomcat\access.20180227.log"
Copy-Item $LogFile "Remote:\" -Force
```

Comment: Oops, I missed the "no UNC path access" part of your question. This probably won't work for you, my bad. Leaving this answer up in-case it can help someone else.

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't work if the host is unreachable via share (NetBios?).